# QListView with Index restoring

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistview

As extension with another question to my previous post. Having `QListView` with saving and restoring selection of items in `QListview`. Indexes of selected item after restoring would not print correctly.

Changing indexes with `currentchange - slot` method, it prints the correct index of selected item in `QListView`. But after rerun of software and restore values, by pressing `okay button` without changing any item, current index should correspond to selected item, but in this case just prints `0`? 
What is it lacking?

[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Helvetica", 8, QtGui.QFont.Normal, italic=False))
        self.setWindowTitle("Getting selected item")
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Okay")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.accept)
        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView()
        lay.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
        lay.addWidget(self.listView)

        self.entry = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.listView.setModel(self.entry)
        self.listView.setSpacing(4)
        self.listView.setFont(
            QtGui.QFont("Helvetica", 9, QtGui.QFont.Normal, italic=False)
        )
        self.listView.setUniformItemSizes(True)
        self.listView.setFixedSize(300, 150)

        Code_Group = QtWidgets.QGroupBox()
        Code_Group.setTitle("&Selecting and deselecting")
        Code_Group.setLayout(lay)

        Vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        Vlay.addWidget(Code_Group)
        Vlay.addWidget(self.button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        Vlay.setSizeConstraint(Vlay.SetFixedSize)

        self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint, True)
        self.read_settings()
        self.listView.selectionModel().currentChanged.connect(self.on_row_changed)

        self.accepted.connect(self.write_settings)

    def on_row_changed(self, current, previous):
        self._INDEX = current.row()
        print('Row %d selected' % current.row())

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print("closeEvent")
        self.write_settings()
        super(Widget, self).closeEvent(event)

    def read_settings(self):
        settings = QtCore.QSettings("file.ini", QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)
        settings.beginGroup("listView")
        model = self.listView.model()
        if settings.contains("items"):

            editTriggers = settings.value(
                "editTriggers", type=QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.EditTriggers
            )
            selectionMode = settings.value(
                "selectionMode", type=QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectionMode
            )
            selectionBehavior = settings.value(
                "selectionBehavior", type=QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectionBehavior
            )
            self.listView.setEditTriggers(editTriggers)
            self.listView.setSelectionMode(selectionMode)
            self.listView.setSelectionBehavior(selectionBehavior)

            items = settings.value("items", type=QtCore.QByteArray)
            stream = QtCore.QDataStream(items, QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly)
            while not stream.atEnd():
                it = QtGui.QStandardItem()
                stream >> it
                model.appendRow(it)
            selecteditems = settings.value("selecteditems", type=list)
            for row in selecteditems:
                index = model.index(row, 0)
                self.listView.selectionModel().select(
                    index, QtCore.QItemSelectionModel.Select
                )
        else:
            for text in [
                "Itemname1",
                "Itemname2",
                "Itemname3",
                "Itemname4",
                "Itemname5",
            ]:
                it = QtGui.QStandardItem(text)
                model.appendRow(it)
                self.listView.setEditTriggers(
                    QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers
                )
                self.listView.setSelectionMode(
                    QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection
                )
                self.listView.setSelectionBehavior(
                    QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows
                )
        settings.endGroup()

    def write_settings(self):
        settings = QtCore.QSettings("file.ini", QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)
        settings.beginGroup("listView")
        model = self.listView.model()

        settings.setValue("editTriggers", self.listView.editTriggers())
        settings.setValue("selectionMode", self.listView.selectionMode())
        settings.setValue("selectionBehavior", self.listView.selectionBehavior())

        items = QtCore.QByteArray()
        stream = QtCore.QDataStream(items, QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
        for i in range(model.rowCount()):
            it = model.item(i)
            stream << it
        settings.setValue("items", items)

        selecteditems = []
        for index in self.listView.selectionModel().selectedRows():
            selecteditems.append(index.row())
        settings.setValue("selecteditems", selecteditems)
        settings.endGroup()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are monitoring the currentIndex hoping that selecting an index will also modify the currentIndex but that is not correct. If you want the currentIndex to be restored then you must also save and restore it.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Helvetica", 8, QtGui.QFont.Normal, italic=False))
        self.setWindowTitle("Getting selected item")
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Okay")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.accept)
        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView()
        lay.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
        lay.addWidget(self.listView)

        self.entry = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.listView.setModel(self.entry)
        self.listView.setSpacing(4)
        self.listView.setFont(
            QtGui.QFont("Helvetica", 9, QtGui.QFont.Normal, italic=False)
        )
        self.listView.setUniformItemSizes(True)
        self.listView.setFixedSize(300, 150)

        Code_Group = QtWidgets.QGroupBox()
        Code_Group.setTitle("&Selecting and deselecting")
        Code_Group.setLayout(lay)

        Vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        Vlay.addWidget(Code_Group)
        Vlay.addWidget(self.button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        Vlay.setSizeConstraint(Vlay.SetFixedSize)

        self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint, True)

        self.listView.selectionModel().currentChanged.connect(self.on_row_changed)
        self.accepted.connect(self.write_settings)

        self.read_settings()

    def on_row_changed(self, current, previous):
        self._INDEX = current.row()
        print("Row %d selected" % current.row())

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print("closeEvent")
        self.write_settings()
        super(Widget, self).closeEvent(event)

    def read_settings(self):
        settings = QtCore.QSettings("file.ini", QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)
        settings.beginGroup("listView")
        model = self.listView.model()
        if settings.contains("items"):

            editTriggers = settings.value(
                "editTriggers", type=QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.EditTriggers
            )
            selectionMode = settings.value(
                "selectionMode", type=QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectionMode
            )
            selectionBehavior = settings.value(
                "selectionBehavior", type=QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectionBehavior
            )
            self.listView.setEditTriggers(editTriggers)
            self.listView.setSelectionMode(selectionMode)
            self.listView.setSelectionBehavior(selectionBehavior)

            items = settings.value("items", type=QtCore.QByteArray)
            stream = QtCore.QDataStream(items, QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly)
            while not stream.atEnd():
                it = QtGui.QStandardItem()
                stream >> it
                model.appendRow(it)
            selecteditems = settings.value("selecteditems", type=list)
            for row in selecteditems:
                index = model.index(row, 0)
                self.listView.selectionModel().setCurrentIndex(
                    index, QtCore.QItemSelectionModel.SelectCurrent
                )
            row = settings.value("currentrow", 0, type=int)
            ix = model.index(row, 0)
            self.listView.setCurrentIndex(ix)
        else:
            for text in [
                "Itemname1",
                "Itemname2",
                "Itemname3",
                "Itemname4",
                "Itemname5",
            ]:
                it = QtGui.QStandardItem(text)
                model.appendRow(it)
                self.listView.setEditTriggers(
                    QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers
                )
                self.listView.setSelectionMode(
                    QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection
                )
                self.listView.setSelectionBehavior(
                    QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows
                )
        settings.endGroup()

    def write_settings(self):
        settings = QtCore.QSettings("file.ini", QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)
        settings.beginGroup("listView")
        model = self.listView.model()

        settings.setValue("editTriggers", self.listView.editTriggers())
        settings.setValue("selectionMode", self.listView.selectionMode())
        settings.setValue("selectionBehavior", self.listView.selectionBehavior())

        items = QtCore.QByteArray()
        stream = QtCore.QDataStream(items, QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
        for i in range(model.rowCount()):
            it = model.item(i)
            stream << it
        settings.setValue("items", items)

        selecteditems = []
        for index in self.listView.selectionModel().selectedRows():
            selecteditems.append(index.row())
        settings.setValue("selecteditems", selecteditems)

        settings.setValue("currentrow", self.listView.currentIndex().row())
        settings.endGroup()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```